# Removing duplicate point features using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, geolocation, remove, duplicates

I have created many *.gpx* data with my Garmin device, but due to the amount of data, I have imported the mapping data from my device several times (also because I didn't want it to be lost).

As a result, I have now many double or even 6 times the same point (including tracks, which I displayed as points also, so that I have the elevation) after I saved all the gpx-files as shapefiles and then merged them.

Is there a way to automatically erase the duplicates with QGIS?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the [mmqgis](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/) Plugin.

There, go to Modify -> delete duplicate geometries and select your layer.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the [`v.clean`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/v.clean.html) tool under GRASS commands in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

To remove duplicates, set the cleaning tool to `rmdupl`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the QGIS built-in tool named ["Delete duplicate geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicate-geometries) under `Processing Toolbox" > Vector general` in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is the SAGA's ["Remove Duplicate Points"](https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/6.1.0/shapes_points_7.html) tool can be found under `SAGA > Features - Points` in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

[image: saga_tool]