# MongoDB Error Code 16755 - Can't extract geo keys for duplicate vertices and edge crossing

Tags: geojson, vertices, mongodb

When I try to create an index on geometry `db.polygons.createIndex({"geometry":"2dsphere"})`, it stops at a certain polygon with the error code 16755. It says it `Can't extract geo key`s and then either `Duplicate vertices: 18 and 20` or `Edges 16 and 18 cross`.

It's nice that MongoDB points out where the problem is. I then go manually remove these nodes in QGIS and re-try the process, only to find there's another polygon with the same issue.

How can I fix this issue without having to repeat the entire process of fixing polygons > uploading to MongoDB > and then attempting to create the index?

Is there a way I can find out how many polygons have this issue? How many of them are malformed according to MongoDB?

edit: I should note that I'm dealing with 25,000 polygons. Hence it would be nice to have a list of all the malformed polygons that MongoDB rejects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hit a similar problem. I just needed to find the valid records in my dataset (I discarded the records with Duplicate Vertices).

I renamed the collection -

```
db.myCollection.renameCollection('myCollectionBk')
```

Then I added a single record from the original collection into a new collection and added a geospatial index to the collection

```
db.myCollection.insert(db.myCollectionBk.findOne()) // recreate the collection
db.myCollection.createIndex({geometry:"2dsphere"}) // create the index (assumes the geometry on the record is valid)
db.myCollection.remove({}) // remove the record
```

Then I added the valid records into the new collection.

```
db.myCollectionBk.find().forEach(function(x){
    db.myCollection.insert(x);
})
```

Invalid records are simply ignored.

In your case you probably want to get the [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#writeresults-insert) from your [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/), and look to see if it was successful. Something like

```
var errors = []
db.myCollectionBk.find().forEach(function(x){
    var result = db.myCollection.insert(x);
    if (result.writeError) {
        errors.push({x._id:result.writeError.errmsg});
    }
})
```

As another alternative, check out [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43961/how-to-remove-duplicate-point-features) (I couldn't get this to work)

Comment: This helped me a ton - only tweak is that newer versions of Mongo have a `writeConcernError` property instead of a `writeError` - details at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#write-concern-errors